# difficulties in JSON forming

Tags: javascript, json

This is the code to form a JSON that a server expects. But there are some problems though

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
//var acc = {};
var x = 10;
var y = 20;
var z = 30;



var output = [];
output[0] = {
    name: "Accelerometer_X",
    value: JSON.parse(x), // retrieve x
};
output[1] = {
    name: "Accelerometer_Y",
    value: JSON.parse(y), // retrieve y
};
output[2] = {
    name: "Accelerometer_Z",
    value: JSON.parse(z) // retrieve z
};

var record = [];
record[0] = {
    starttime: new Date(),
    output: output,
};

var observations = [];
observations[0] = {
    sensor: "",
    record: record,
};

var fromData = {};
fromData.version = "1.0.1";
fromData.observations = observations;
alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));
console.log(JSON.stringify(fromData));
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output JSON is:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "observations": [
        {
            "sensor": "",
            "record": [
                {
                    "starttime": "2014-08-15T16:01:34.711Z",
                    "output": [
                        {
                            "name": "Accelerometer_X",
                            "value": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Accelerometer_Y",
                            "value": 20
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Accelerometer_Z",
                            "value": 30
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But the expected JSON is:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "observations": [
        {
            "sensor": "",
            "record": [
                {
                    "starttime": "1-JAN-2014 15:30:00 IST",
                    "output": [
                        {
                            "name": "Accelerometer_X",
                            "value": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Accelerometer_Y",
                            "value": "20"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Accelerometer_Z",
                            "value": "30"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The values in expected JSON is within "" ie.

```
                    {
                        "name": "Accelerometer_Z",
                        "value": "30"
                    }
```

But the produced JSON is :

```
                    {
                        "name": "Accelerometer_Z",
                        "value": 30
                    }
```

And there is another problem that is the starttime. The expected starttime format is

```
1-JAN-2014 15:30:00 IST
```

The produced starttime is:

```
2014-08-15T16:01:34.711Z
```

I do not know how to change this. Please help me out.

Comment: The numbers are showing without the quotes because they are numbers. If you want to add quotes you can cast it to a string but it's correct without them

Comment: Why do you want to make the numbers strings? They're numbers.

Comment: Separately, I would recommend *not* sending the time in IST. Send it in the pseudo-ISO-8601 format that JSON.stringify defaults to, it's much more reliable.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Because then only the server accepts. That is how the format MUST BE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `JSON.parse` on the values that you want to put in the object. The `JSON.parse` method is used to parse a JSON string into an object, but the values are not JSON strings.

Remove the `JSON.parse` call (as it doesn't change the value), and use the `toString` method to turn the values into strings:

```
output[0] = {
    name: "Accelerometer_X",
    value: x.toString(),
};
output[1] = {
    name: "Accelerometer_Y",
    value: y.toString(),
};
output[2] = {
    name: "Accelerometer_Z",
    value: z.toString()
};
```

---

There is no build in function that formats the date that way, you would need to make your own. Something like:

```
function formatDate(d) {
  return d.getDate() + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getFullYear() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds() + " IST";
}
```

Usage:

```
record[0] = {
    starttime: formatDate(new Date()),
    output: output,
};
```

Comment: yeah it is working. Thanks man :)
can you resolve this time format issue too ?

Comment: @anupam_on: I added some code for that too, see if it is useful.

Comment: yes, worked, thanks a lot man and formatted date too. will post that shortly for others, if need :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code so far working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
//var acc = {};
var x = 10;
var y = 20;
var z = 30;

//var accString = JSON.stringify(acc); // that's what you have

var output = [];
output[0] = {
    name: "Accelerometer_X",
    value: x.toString(), // retrieve x
};
output[1] = {
    name: "Accelerometer_Y",
    value: y.toString(), // retrieve y
};
output[2] = {
    name: "Accelerometer_Z",
    value: z.toString() // retrieve z
};

var record = [];
record[0] = {
    starttime: new Date(),
    output: output,
};

var observations = [];
observations[0] = {
    sensor: "",
    record: record,
};

var fromData = {};
fromData.version = "1.0.1";
fromData.observations = observations;
alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));
console.log(JSON.stringify(fromData));
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the time is having problem still now. Anyone to resolve this issue?